# Is there a way to increase the ammo capacity for Sleep Darts?

Tags: dishonored

I see the upgrade to increase bolt capacity for normal bolts, but not sleep bolts.  I didn't know if the sleep bolt might be a blueprint that I missed or have yet to come upon, but it seemed strange that there was no corresponding increase for them.

Is there a blueprint to increase sleep bolt ammunition capacity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. The cap is ten, use them wisely!

Comment: I wonder if that cap can be changed via an ini setting...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of as I'd not found anything else about it anywhere.  Thanks!

Comment: If I had to guess, I suspect that the reason for that upgrade not being availiable is that unlimited sleep darts can trivialize no-kill/ghost runs. Really, the only thing that prevents sleep darts from being gamebreaking is their scarcity.